# Approximate arbitrary covariance matrix using kernel

Tags: covariance-matrix, kernel-trick, gaussian-process

I would like to approximate a arbitrary covariance matrix using a kernel.
In hear kernel can only be summation or multiplication of each kernel (rbf, linear ,periodic, constant). I don't want to use like a spectral mixture kernel.

Any help or reference please?